# UTF-8 not working nginx

Tags: php, utf-8, nginx

I have a self-hosted server running nginx and PHP5-fpm on a debian (raspbian wheezy) machine.

My problem is UTF-8 special characters (åäö) aren't working. I've set `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the head of the website. All files are encoded with utf-8 without BOM.

As adviced by Fleshgrinder's answer I've added `charset utf-8;` to nginx.conf without results.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your files must be in UTF-8 as well and the HTTP header you send is more important than the meta tag.

To deliver all your content with UTF-8 encoding (HTTP header) via nginx do the following:

```
# /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

http {
    charset utf-8;
}
```

But the important part is that your files actually have to be encoded in UTF-8 for anything to work. A good editor (e.g. Notepad2, Notepad++, NetBeans IDE, Adobe Dreamweaver, …) allows you to change the encoding of your file.

Comment: Yeah, the files are all utf-8 without BOM. Adding `charset utf-8;` in nginx.conf didn't solve the problem. I'll add this to the question. What exactly do you mean by "HTTP header you send"? I'm a noob.

Comment: Nevermind, google'd it and setting `<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>`at the top of the document fixed it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can also set `default_charset = utf-8` in your `php.ini`. Glad I was from help.

Comment: @justanotherhobbyist the Unicode Standard neither requires nor recommends the use of the BOM for UTF-8. Please **avoid Microsoft** (does not respect standards), and use [universal stantard UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) in **all ecosystem**: compliant editors, compliant git, and all sources (HTML, PHP, Javascript, etc.).